# What else does ZFC prove about the "spectrum" of a cardinal number?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, filters

An auxiliary definition:

> **Definition 0.** Given an infinite set $X$ and a filter $\mathcal{F}$ on $X$, let $\sim_\mathcal{F}$ denote the equivalence relation on $\mathcal{P}(X)$ defined as follows: $A \sim_\mathcal{F} B$ iff we can find $K \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $A \cap K = B \cap K$.

Now for the main one:

> **Definition 1.** By the *spectrum* of a cardinal number $\kappa$, I simply mean the set of all infinite cardinal numbers $\nu$ such that there exists a filter $\mathcal{F}$ on $\mathcal{P}(\kappa)$ satisfying $|\mathcal{P}(\kappa)/\!\sim_{\mathcal{F}}\!| = \nu$.
>
> Write $\mathrm{Spec}(\kappa)$ for the spectrum of $\kappa$.

Clearly, if $\kappa$ is an infinite cardinal number, then $2^\kappa \in \mathrm{Spec}(\kappa).$ But honestly, that's about all I can show!

> **Questions.** What else does ZFC prove about $\mathrm{Spec}(\kappa)$? In particular:
>
> 1. Given $\nu \in \mathrm{Spec}(\kappa)$ and $\nu'$ in the interval $[\nu,2^\kappa]$, can we conclude that $\nu' \in \mathrm{Spec}(\kappa)$?
> 2. Is it a general fact that $\kappa^+ \in \mathrm{Spec}(\kappa)$? (Note that this follows from GCH.)
> 3. Is it a general fact that $\kappa \in \mathrm{Spec}(\kappa)$? If not, does this imply an outright contradiction?

I'm also curious to know whether the existence of cardinal numbers that do not belong to $\mathrm{Spec}(\kappa)$ for any $\kappa$ is consistent with ZFC.

Comment: Trivially $\operatorname{Spec}(\kappa)$ contains $\operatorname{Spec}(\lambda)$ for all $\lambda\leq\kappa$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not too hard to show that $\operatorname{Spec}(\kappa)$ contains no cardinals smaller than $2^{\aleph_0}$.  Indeed, let $F$ be any filter on $\mathcal{P}(\kappa)$ such that the quotient $B=\mathcal{P}(\kappa)/F$ is infinite.  Since $B$ is an infinite Boolean algebra, we can find an infinite sequence of disjoint nonzero elements of $B$, and by induction we can find representatives $a_n\in\mathcal{P}(\kappa)$ of these elements which are actually disjoint in $\mathcal{P}(\kappa)$.  For any $S\subseteq \omega$, let $a_S=\bigcup_{n\in S} a_n$.  Then for $S\neq T$, $a_S\neq a_T$ mod $F$, since their symmetric difference contains some $a_n$.  Thus $S\mapsto a_S$ is an injective homomorphism $\mathcal{P}(\omega)\to B$.

Comment: Interesting. How did you know that $\mathcal{P}(\kappa)/\!\sim_\kappa$ was a Boolean algebra? Is it a complete Boolean algebra?

Comment: What you call $\mathcal{P}(\kappa)/\sim_F$ is just what is usually called the Boolean algebra quotient $\mathcal{P}(\kappa)/I$, where $I$ is the ideal consisting of the complements of all the elements of $F$.  In the language of Boolean rings, $I$ is a (ring) ideal and the quotient is just the usual quotient ring.  In general the quotient has no reason to be complete, though it will be if $F$ is complete (i.e., closed under arbitrary intersections, which for filters in $\mathcal{P}(\kappa)$ just means $F$ is principal).

Comment: Where does one learn this stuff?

Comment: Any introduction to Boolean algebras will cover all of this.  I learned it from Halmos's Lectures on Boolean Algebras, but I'm sure there are many other references.

Comment: Okay, thanks. $\;\!$

Comment: @goblin The question about when quotient Boolean algebras are complete is surprisingly difficult and has connections to large cardinals. For example, if $\kappa\geq\omega_3$ has a nonprincipal $\kappa$-complete ideal $I$ such that $\mathcal{P}(\kappa)/I$ is complete then $\kappa$ must be measurable in an inner model.